# Placing two different maps on item frames next to each other causes both of them to show the same map

Tags: xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console

I am having an issue with maps in item frames in the xbox one version, but I cannot seem to find anyone with the same issue posted online.

If I put up an item frame, then put in a map, all is good. But if I put up a second frame beside it, and put a different map into it, both maps change to look like the new one. If I delete one, the other returns to normal. The same happens if I put up 4 different maps, they all become the most recent one until they are removed.

Is there a way around this?